# How to resist added the data added at runtime by JavaScript in a website without using a server and a database

Tags: javascript, browser, devops, serverless

**Introduction**
I was making a web app in which users can add their code snippets and access it from everywhere and copy those code snippets added by them.

**Links**
[Github Repo](https://github.com/hamiecod/CodeSnip)

**The Process**
I chose to build the project without a server and a database, so all the logic and calculations were being done in the client side(browser). When I came on to writing the logic for adding the snippets, I faced a big problem, which was that I could add the code snippets at runtime in the browser, but the code snippets won't just retain in the website and vanish on reload, that was because I didn't have a database and server setup to store the code snippets.

**The Problem**

1. The snippets do not retain in the website due to the absence of a server and database

**What is the question?**

1. Can I somehow add markup to the actual HTML file from the browser runtime? If yes, how?
2. Can I use Ajax and web sockets or something else to send data from the browser runtime to an API, from where I can fetch the data and add to HTML, if yes then how?

**Note:**
Doing this serverless and without a database might be inefficient but this project needs to be only client side.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. You want a user to be able to store and access code snippets from everywhere, but without storing them in a database? from what it sounds like, these code snippets need to get stored somewhere, so you're going to need to use some sort of database. You could also reach for less common solutions, like storing them in a hidden directory in the user's Google Drive (if you want to link your app to Google Drive).

Comment: @ScottyJamison I want to store the code snippets and make them accessible, is there somehow I can append the ACTUAL HTML files(the markup files) when an event is triggered in the browswer?